# Iterate over loop to get cumsum for a dataframe variable for each different date variable (Not Aggregation)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a simple code in which I have units produced in a dataframe 'Yield' and 'Date' on which they were produced. Multiple records are present for the same date. I am going to use numpy cumsum function to get running total for each row and then subtract the value for the current row. I do not wish to do aggregation for the date since I need the original raw records to remain.

I can do this for one set of date by having `.loc` variable made for each date and then apply the function. But can't figure out how to do this iteratively.

```
data_43102 = data['Yield_Done','PDate'].loc[data['PDate'] ==43102]
#gives me Yield Done for only 43102

data_43102['Running_total']=  cumsum(data_43102['Yield_Done']) #gives me cumulative total 

data_43102['Running_total'] = data_43102['Running_total'] - data_43102['Yield_Done']
```

Whet I expect after running the code is there to be output like in the case of one I had [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the dates in a list and then use `isin` to get data filtered for all the dates:

```
dates = ['43102', '23102', '43102'...]

data_filtered_by_date = data['Yield_Done','PDate'].loc[data['PDate'].isin(dates)]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks a lot. I tried earlier by putting the dates in array but was getting errors in the comparison under loc (The truth value of a Series is ambiguous..). Did not think putting in list would be an easy work around. Thanks a bunch really!!

Comment: You're welcome. You may consider upvoting/accepting the answer.